# Using 'as T' in function type signature

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust but I'm already familiar with Generics. At least that's what I thought until I came across this trait definition (edited for brevity):

```
pub trait Queue<Item: ItemT>: Core<Item> {
    fn validate(
        &self,
        hash: <Item as ItemT>::Hash
    ) -> bool;
}
```

What's this `Item as ItemT` thing? Isn't `Item` already of type `ItemT`? I'm also perplexed by the syntax `<Item as ItemT>::Hash` ... what's that supposed to be? Is it the same as `ItemT::Hash`? If yes, then why not say so?

Also, incidentally, does the syntax `: Core<Item>` mean that the `Queue` trait requires all implementors to also implement the `Core` trait? Or does it mean something else? And why would you do that? Who cares about `Core`? If somebody needs the `Core` trait, can't they just say so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's this `Item as ItemT` thing?

`<Item as ItemT>::` is how you specify associated item (type, method, constant) from *the implementation of the trait `ItemT` for the type `Item`*.

For a less complex example, suppose we have some type `Foo` that implements the [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) trait. Then the following are all ways of calling the same function:

```rust
let a: Foo = Default::default();
let b = Foo::default();
let c = <Foo as Default>::default();
```

and their particular characteristics are that:

- `a` depends on having the result type specified to infer which type should be used with the Default trait.
- `b` might be referring to an *inherent* (non-trait) associated function of `Foo`, rather than the one from `Default`, if someone wrote

  ```rust
  impl Foo { fn default() { ... } }
  ```
- `c` is fully specified.

> I'm also perplexed by the syntax `<Item as ItemT>::Hash` ... what's that supposed to be? Is it the same as `ItemT::Hash`?

Yes.

> If yes, then why not say so?

I don't know the exact logic, but often the compiler requires you to specify *which trait* (`ItemT`) the associated type (`Hash`) came from — even if you might think it was obvious. I presume this is in order to avoid future ambiguity if additional traits define associated types that might have the same name `Hash`.

> does the syntax `: Core<Item>` mean that the `Queue` trait requires all implementors to also implement the `Core` trait?

Yes, precisely so. This syntax is called [supertraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#supertraits).

> And why would you do that? Who cares about `Core`? If somebody needs the `Core` trait, can't they just say so?

In some cases, trait bounds would get very verbose if every required trait had to be spelled out for every generic function. But more generally, it's used when the requirement is a logical necessity, “it cannot possibly make sense to implement trait A and not implement trait B”, or at least when that would be very impractical (the library design chooses not to support the cases where `B` would not be implemented).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax `<Type as Trait>::Item` is the [fully-qualified syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name) used to explicitly refer to an associated `Item` of a `Trait` on a `Type`. This is not terribly common to write out yourself, but you may need to if there is an ambiguity in what `Item` means for a `Type`.

Consider this modified example using `Self::Hash` where the current trait and supertrait both have a `Hash` associated type:

```
trait Core<Item> {
    type Hash;
}

trait Queue<Item>: Core<Item> {
    type Hash;
    fn validate(
        &self,
        hash: Self::Hash
    ) -> bool;
}
```

```
error[E0221]: ambiguous associated type `Hash` in bounds of `Self`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:15
  |
2 |     type Hash;
  |     ---------- ambiguous `Hash` from `Core<Item>`
...
6 |     type Hash;
  |     ---------- ambiguous `Hash` from `Queue<Item>`
...
9 |         hash: Self::Hash
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type `Hash`
  |
help: use fully qualified syntax to disambiguate
  |
9 |         hash: <Self as Queue<Item>>::Hash
  |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: use fully qualified syntax to disambiguate
  |
9 |         hash: <Self as Core<Item>>::Hash
  |               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In this case, it is ambiguous what `Self::Hash` means, so the compiler requires that you fully-qualify what trait to use.

---

You may also see this syntax used in generated documentation. As an example, take the [`str::rmatches`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.rmatches) function. The original signature is written like so:

```
pub fn rmatches<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> RMatches<'a, P>
where
    P: Pattern<'a, Searcher: ReverseSearcher<'a>>
```

But it shows up in the documentation like this:

```
pub fn rmatches<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> RMatches<'a, P>
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
    <P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: ReverseSearcher<'a>,
```

Not exactly sure why this is; perhaps the designers thought disambiguation was a good idea by default, it was simpler this way, or if it was just better for generating links. Either way, its something you'll come across so its better to learn it and not get confused later.

---

In your particular example, I don't see why `Item::Hash` would need to be qualified, but perhaps there is more at play than what is shown, could simply be a fluke, or maybe its just an artifact caused by a previous version of the code.

> Also, incidentally, does the syntax `: Core<Item>` mean that the `Queue` trait requires all implementors to also implement the `Core` trait? Or does it mean something else? And why would you do that? Who cares about `Core`? If somebody needs the `Core` trait, can't they just say so?

Yes, this is constraining the `Queue<Item>` trait that any implementation must also implement `Core<Item>`. `Core<Item>` is also called a supertrait with this usage.

This snippet is a bit too reduced to definitively say why that would be desired, but consider something like [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) which has `Iterator` as a supertrait since it makes no sense for something to be a double-ended iterator but not be an iterator. So its often used in similar scenarios where it makes no sense to use use the subtrait independently.

But your instincts are good; if a trait can reasonably be used without the supertrait, then it shouldn't.